# How to work with dot as decimalseperator on every system in c#

Tags: c#

i try to recalculate the E values of out CSV file.
So i have to find all values of *E=(24.6)* to multiply by 7.6 and write back *E=(186.96)*

I have the code to get the value *24.6* and can convert it to double *24,6*
but i want double as *24.6*

Can you help me to set my decimalseperator in program to *.* and not to Systemdefinition.

```
static void parseCommand(string commands)
{
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
    nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    Double conv = 0;
    string[] command = commands.Split(' ');

    foreach (var commando in command)
    {
        if (commando != "")
        {
            if (commando.Contains("E=("))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(commando, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value + " Regex.Match");
                conv = Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match(commando, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value, nfi);

                System.Console.WriteLine(conv + " converted");
                System.Console.WriteLine(commando + " original\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

console output

```
24.6 Regex.Match
24,6 converted
E=(24.6) original
```

converted should be 24.6

Comment: Use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, pass it as the second argument to Convert.ToDouble().  Do favor Double.TryParse(), a typo is not an error.

Comment: conv = Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match(commando, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

so i get also in converted the *,* and no *.*

Comment: `System.Console.WriteLine(conv + " converted");` will use your default number format, so perhaps `System.Console.WriteLine(conv.ToString(nfi) + " converted");` is what you need?

Comment: works thank you Mark

Comment: You can also specify the culture that should be used by default for operations on the current thread with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`. This may or may not be desirable in this scenario, but it can be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

When printing your `double` value, you also need to specify the number format/culture.  You could use `nfi` in the `WriteLine` statement:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(conv.ToString(nfi) + " converted");
```

Or, as Hans said, you could use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `nfi` for both parsing and formatting:

```
conv = Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match(commando, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// ...
System.Console.WriteLine(conv.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " converted");
```